# Finding dates for manipulation in an Excel Range with C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a situation where I am working with an Excel workbook and I would like to find each cell that has a date in it to do some work on that cell specifically. The dates are in columns, but from what I have read, it seems to be easier just to grab the entire used range and check the cells. Unfortunately, what I am finding is that once I have the cells, I cannot detect a date within them. Here is the contents of the method I am using:

```
Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
Excel.Range range = sheet.UsedRange;
//get an array of values from the cells
System.Array cellvals = (System.Array)range.Cells.Value2;
//go through each 
foreach(object obj in cellvals)
{
    //is it a datetime?
    DateTime testdt = new DateTime();
    double holder = 0.00;
    if (double.TryParse(obj.ToString(),out holder)) 
    {
        bool test = DateTime.TryParse(holder.ToString(), out testdt);
        if (test)
        {
            //check it against litmus test
            Console.WriteLine("Hit");
        }
     }
}
```

Even though I have a column of dates in my test data, the `if(test)` conditional is never entered. Here is an example of one of the strings in the date column:

`01/08/2007 14:50:50.42`

Most of what I have found online has been about finding very specific date strings, and not just dates in general. I was hoping someone might be able to help me find why I am not hitting that conditional as expected.

Comment: for this line `DateTime testdt = new DateTime();` do you even use the debugger..? because inside your foreach loop you are creating a new instance of DateTime.. if your cells have a date field.. then you need to know what field in the cellvals is the DateTime field.. it's obvious why this line never gets hit.. start with debugging your code and setting breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Using the approach you've taken above, you cannot differentiate between a cell that contains a double and one that contains a true date/time. Also, you can't parse the string representation of a Double as a DateTime. There are ways to convert from an OLE DATE (which is just a double) to a .NET DateTime, but you may not need to do that.

Have you seen this note on the documentation of the [Value2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value2.aspx) property?

> The only difference between this property and the **Value** property is that the **Value2** property doesn’t use the **Currency** and **Date** data types. You can return values formatted with these data types as floating-point numbers by using the **Double** data type.

Use the [Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value.aspx) property instead, and I believe you'll get .NET DateTimes where you expect them.

Comment: Well, that is what I get for copying and pasting and not completely understanding what I was using. Thank you for your help! It works now.

Comment: The overall goal I am going for here is to find any date over a specific value and change the background on that cell. Is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: Probably. You may just want to use Excel's conditional formatting. You can either manually apply it (if it's just a one-time thing you're trying to set up) or you can do it programmatically. I've answered your original question, and I'll leave it to you to investigate the right way to solve your problem.

Comment: To investigate conditional formatting: 1) Enable your Developer tab ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx ). 2) Create a sheet with a column of dates. 3) Select that range of date cells. 4) Start recording a macro (Developer tab => Record Macro). 5) Manually apply conditional formatting (Home tab => Conditional Formatting). 6) Stop recording macro (Developer tab => Stop Recording). 7) Look at the generated VBA (Developer tab => Visual Basic, find the Module that was created).